# Как передать большой файл с помощью WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

При попытке передать файл (до 50 мб все ОК) получаю такую ошибку :

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8090/RemoteAccessService/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Вот код клиента :

```
using (RemoteAccessClient client = new RemoteAccessClient("basicHttpBinding_RemoteAccessServise"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("...");
    string from = @"C://test.7z";
    Stream stream;
    Console.WriteLine(from);

    stream = client.GetFile(from);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Сервис :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRemoteAccess
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetFile(string path);
}

public class RemoteAccessService : IRemoteAccess
{
public Stream GetFile(string path)
{
  FileInfo f = new FileInfo(path);
  return f.OpenRead();
}
}
```

Конфиг клиента :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="01:00:00"/>

    </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_RemoteAccessServise" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
            maxBufferSize="409600" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize= "2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" transferMode="Streamed">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8090/RemoteAccessService/"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_RemoteAccessServise"
          contract="RemoteService.IRemoteAccess" name="basicHttpBinding_RemoteAccessServise" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Конфиг сервиса :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"
    executionTimeout="01:00:00"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RemoteAccessServiceLib.RemoteAccessService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="RemoteAccessServiceLib.IRemoteAccess"
                  bindingName="basicHttpBinding_RemoteAccessServise" name="basicHttpBinding_RemoteAccessServise">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8090/RemoteAccessService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_RemoteAccessServise" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
            maxBufferSize="409600" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize= "2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>   
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Хостится сервис в консольном приложении. И всем кто хотя бы дочитал до конца, спасибо!

Comment: Вроде бы у Вас всё отключено, что может мешать. Странно.

Comment: В крайнем случае, можете отказаться от использования Stream и вручную разбивать файл несколькими операциями.

Comment: Странно то, что легко передаются файлы до 50 мб.

Преобразовать в массив байтов и передавать по кускам этот массив, правильно ли я Вас понял ? Не могли ли бы Вы помочь с реализацией(в общих чертах) ?

Вот исходники: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mhkfc8lqoa4czsm/0TzgzR5Uvi

Comment: Удачно получил байты из файлы размером 200 с лишним метров. Как повторить проблему?

Comment: Wind, не поверите, но запустил на домашнем ноуте и все работает. Спасибо что заставили еще раз посмотреть на эту проблему.

Comment: Просто как совет: Если это ещё возможно на текщем этапе проекта - перейдите на REST.. Сейчас вы тратите довольно немало ресурсов на преобразования бинарных данных в base64 и обратно для передачи их в виде пакета XML-SOAP. В случае же с REST, такие преобразования не требуется - бинарные данные обычно передаются как есть.

Answer (score 3):

SO: [What is the maximum size that maxReceivedMessageSize can be set to for a NetNamedPipeBinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004717/what-is-the-maximum-size-that-maxreceivedmessagesize-can-be-set-to-for-a-netname)

Попробуйте изменить значение `maxReceivedMessageSize` и `maxBufferPoolSize` до `9223372036854775807` и увеличить `TimeOut`, да и такой вопрос вы используете *IIS* или *IIS Express*?

Answer (score -1):

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```